# Varbinary always is null at WCF service

Tags: sql-server, wcf, enterprise-library, varbinary

my DAL is something like this:

```
Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>();
mylist = db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<EMyClass>("spMySP", param1, param2).ToList();
```

my SP in SQL-SEVER returns 4 normal fields plus a varbinary field that is an image

my EMyClass is:

```
public class EMyClass
{

    public int aaa { get; set; }
    public int bbb { get; set; }
    public byte[] ccc { get; set; }
    public string ddd { get; set; }
    public string eee { get; set; }
}
```

At the WCF client i can see the normal data from any row returned by the query, but the varbinary field (image) is always null, when i execute the same query at the sql manager i can see the varbinary field with the image data. The varbinary field is supposed to map to the ccc property of the class.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know, it could be the worst approach but at least its working -_-

```
foreach (EMyClass obj in mylist)
    obj.ccc = (byte[])db.ExecuteScalar("spReturnImage", obj.aaa);
```